# How to use the System.Threading.Tasks Class on .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-framework-version, downgrade

Now, the based project has used `System.Threading.Tasks` Class on `.NET Framework 4.0`, but need to target for `.NET Framework 3.5`
how to do it? Import any dll? thanks for your answer.

Comment: What project? What code? Why would you want to do this? (While formally supported .NET 3.5 was replaced by 4.x years ago.)

Comment: a shadowsocks project, it is based on .NET 4.0.  but on windows7, .Net framework 35 is the default configuration. so need to move to .Net35

Comment: @S.Akbari, add it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `System.Threading.Tasks.Unofficial` or `TaskParallelLibrary` are good choices for you. Take a look at the following packages on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Unofficial/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary/

Comment: for the TaskParallelLibrary, is there any doc to descript this package? CLASS description and some uses cases.

Comment: @James All the notes and documents should be found here https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary/